# Get the most recently updated file in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the latest updated file from number of files present under that directory starting with name file_(random number).css?
there are number of file present like this:

```
file_12.css
file_34.css
file_14.css
```

I want to get the most recently updated file. is there any readymade function available to retrieve such file in PHP?

Comment: Yes, http://php.net/filemtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
int filemtime ( string $filename )
```

Info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

```
string readdir ([ resource $dir_handle ] )
```

Info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

or

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )
```

Info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use a combination of `filemtime` and `readdir` to read all of the file's names and last updated time into an array (with the modified time as the key and the filename as the value), use a sorting function, and then grab the file with the greatest modified time.

Something like the following should do the trick (not tested):

```
<?php

$files = array();

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (is_file($file)) {
            $modified = filemtime($file);
            $files[$modified] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

krsort($files);

$last_modified_file = array_shift($files);
```

Comment: this led me in the right direction, the only issue I had was when using `filemtime()` you need to use the entire path `filemtime('/path/to/files/'.$file)` not just the local filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
if(!is_file($b) || !strpos('file_', $b)) return -1;
$a = filemtime($a); 
$b = filemtime($b);   
return  ($a == $b) ? 0 :( ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1 );
}
usort($handle = scandir('/path/to/files'), "cmp");
$file = $handle[0];
unset($handle);
```